# Command+Tab not working on MacOSX Client with Synergy

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, synergy

I have an Ubuntu 11.10 laptop paired with an Apple Wireless Keyboard. I'm using the answer on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/277990/how-do-i-swap-alt-and-windows-keys-with-xmodmap) to swap the Command and Option keys so that they are mapped like a regular keyboard. This works fine in Ubuntu.

Now I have a Macbook Pro running as a Synergy Client. This mapping kind of works on the Macbook, but it only allows me to Command+Tab between two programs, not all of them. Copy, Paste, and other Command keys seem to work fine, but not Command+Tab. It's annoying just because I use the keyboard a lot.

And yes, I could switch to syncing the keyboard and the Macbook, but I use the Ubuntu laptop more.