# Switching left alt and left win

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, setxkbmap

I have a Thinkpad X230 (german layout, [edit]running linux[/edit]) and I want to switch the left win- and the left alt-key somehow with the right alt-key (AltGr) not being touched.

However, I haven't found a working solution yet. I know the question dealing with exactely this problem here on superuser ([How do I swap Alt and Windows keys with xmodmap?](https://superuser.com/questions/277990/how-do-i-swap-alt-and-windows-keys-with-xmodmap)), but the xmodmaps there just give me an error:

> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
>
> Value in failed request:  0x17
>
> Serial number of failed request:  13
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  13

And as the Keyboardmodel is a different one, I don't know which setxkbmap-command is required.

What I tried so far (besides the Xmodmaps in the question mentioned above) is
* "setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_lalt_lwin", which does exactely nothing
* some xmodmap-variations (unfortunately I do not remember which combinations I tried, however, I wasn't able to make it work), my last status with most of my used commands is this one:

> !!Clear Super & Alt
>
> !clear Mod1
>
> !clear Mod4
>
> !remove mod1 = Alt_L
>
> !remove mod4 = Super_L
>
> !keycode 204 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
>
> !keycode 205 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
>
> !keycode 206 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
>
> !keycode 207 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
>
> !
>
> !keycode 64 = Super_L Super_L Super_L Super_L
>
> !keycode 133 = Alt_L Alt_L Alt_L Alt_L
>
> !keysym Alt_L = Super_L
>
> !keysym Super_L = Alt_L
>
> !Remap Super & Alt
>
> !add mod1    = Super_L
>
> !add mod4    = Alt_L

Is someone experienced in using xmodmap or setxkbmap and can me help out? It would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is clean and a built in function:

```
setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_lalt_lwin
```

(I am using it for my Thinkpad X260) on Fedora 27 and the Windowmanager Xmonad, which uses the Super_L key as as ModMask.)